# non latin characters in popupmenu caption

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I Have a Simple popup menu in a `vcl` application , but there is something weird happened when i write `non-latin characters` into the `popup-menu` `Caption`

the characters written correctly but it has this extra characters added **(Z)** at the end of the caption. this characters only added when i type non-latin words into the caption , English words shows correctly .

here is the dfm of the test project

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  BorderIcons = [biSystemMenu]
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 242
  ClientWidth = 472
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PopupMenu = PopupMenu1
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu
    Left = 232
    Top = 128
    object N1: TMenuItem
      Caption = #1575#1604#1604#1594#1577' '#1575#1604#1593#1585#1576#1610#1577
    end
  end
end
```

and this is an image of how the result comes out . this extra **(Z)** i did not write it into the caption at all . i don't know why its showing any idea why ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TPopupMenu` tries to automatically set a hotkey for each menu item (if you didn't do this manually by using `&` char). You can change your `PopupMenu.AutoHotkeys` property value to `maManual` if you want to avoid this behaviour.